# Unzipping Large Files in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, perl, amazon-s3, compression, unzip

We've recently ran into an issue with file corruption after large files are unzipped. The unzip process completes without error but can be missing last 5k bytes.

Our current process: A .ZIP file is downloaded from S3 onto the linux pod, perl code using `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` unzips a single .JSON file, the .JSON is uploaded back to S3.

There is another layer of challenge too. When using native windows or linux tools locally the files unzip completely, no missing bytes. However, at times single characters are changed within the file (We've seen corrupted JSON, changing "}]}" to }M}" or misspelled words, "item" to "idem"). This problem seems worse with tools like 7zip and Winrar.

In checking the details on the .ZIP file it looks to using windows for the encoding compression, which research says uses a GBK encoding. I suspect there may be a decoding issue with linux and some tools that use UTF8 decoding, but I've been unable to confirm that. Plus, we've experienced even the local windows unzip process changing single characters.

We've tried using `IO::Uncompress::Unzip` locally, which resulted in incomplete file.
We've tried using `Archive::Zip` locally, which errors out on any files over 4 GB.
We've tried using `Compress::Raw::Zlib`, but that also didn't work.
We've tried `autoflush` on the file handle, which resulted in incomplete file.

Has anyone encountered similar behaviors?

Comment: It's going to be difficult to get a good answer to this without code. The problem probably has to do with the specific way you're using the modules.

Comment: *"We've tried using IO::Uncompress::Unzip locally, which resulted in incomplete file."* So this happens only when file size is larger than 4GB ? Does this happen for any zipped file type (not just a zipped json file) ?

Comment: When you get errors unzipping using the command-line, does this happen consistently? In order words, if you download a file with `aws s3 cp s3://something something`, and then unzip it, do you _always_ get the same output?

Comment: Smells like the input file(s) is the problem, when even windows zip doesn't like it. what is producing it? are there other processes that use the file ok? what is producing the json in the file? maybe it is already faulty before it gets even zipped